# Custom setting List vs Hierarchy

Tags: customsetting

What is the difference between Custom Setting Type "List" and "Hierachy"?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

What's your use case? One will fit better than the other.

**Hierarchy custom settings** can be configured at varying user specificity levels under a *single* name; the platform will look for the most specific configuration first, then fall back / inherit to the least specific:

- setting per user,
- setting per profile,
- setting for whole org,

Hierarchy custom settings are easily retrieved in Visualforce: `{!$Setup.Setting__c.Field__c}` and will be resolved according to the current user context.

[image: hierarchy custom setting]

**List custom settings** have user-independent values, retrieved under *multiple* names. For example, you could use several configs to hold the credentials for a web service callout so that you can swap the endpoints:

- setting for development environment,
- setting for volume testing environment,
- setting for production environment,

List custom settings need to be accessed using a controller if you want to avail them on a page, for example `return ListSetting__c.getInstance('dev').Field__c;`

[image: list custom setting]

Comment: I might adjust the wording of the last statement, as you typically wouldn't want to "query" a custom setting in Apex, you use an accessor method to retrieve the cached setting values. But good answer otherwise.

Comment: At the moment I don't have complicated use cases, I have been working with List most of the time, I didn't have a clue what Hierarchy was, and wanted a clear explanation that showed the differences between List and Hierachy, thanks, i'll be checking that out!

Comment: Might want to explicitly state that you can only access one Hierarchy Setting record (it's implied in your answer but could be missed).

Comment: Great answer. I would suggest amending from "Sometimes one or the other is a more appropriate fit..." to "One or the other is always a more appropriate fit..." since they are so different in their usage. Lists are great for global registry-like settings, and hierarchy are great for settings that may need different values for different groups or individual users. I've never seen a requirement that could "correctly" be satisfied by either - one is always more appropriate than other, but both are very useful.

Comment: thanks WesNolte and @jkraybill - I've differentiated 'org-wide under multiple names' vs 'user-specific under a singular name'

Comment: Very nice answer buddy! Screenshots with drop-shadows - what the... ;-) I would perhaps suggest providing a different example use case for list settings - I think the docs use tax codes - to distinguish the types even more clearly

Comment: you'll need two hands @StephenWillcock, Command + Shift  + 4 + Space + Click

Comment: what if you dont want to hard code the getInstance() variable? I want my environments to determine which custom setting url i get returned