# Regarding Custom settings in salesforce

Tags: customsetting

**why formula fields are working only in Hierarchy custom settings,not in list custom settings what is the Difference between list custom settings and Hierarchy custom Settings**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

formula fields cant access the list type custom setting because in list type custom setting we can store multiple rows and u need to search from that rows, unlikely in hierarchy there will only single value for one field so you can easily get that values.

check this [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8887/custom-setting-list-vs-hierarchy) for difference between Hierarchy and list custom settings